# Can I use postman for onCall methods made as functions in firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, postman

So I've made this very simple method, where I want to sign in with to firebase using a custom token. As of right now it's simply

```
export const createCustomToken = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    try {
        const firebaseJWT = await authenticationProvider.createCustomToken()
        console.log(firebaseJWT.toString())
    } catch (err) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'Something went wrong ');
    }
});
```

The authenticationProvider looks like this:

```
return firebase.admin.auth().createCustomToken("Some uid")
       .then((token) => {
           console.log("Did create custom token.");
           return token;
       }).catch((error) => {
           console.log("Error creating custom token:" + error);
           throw new firebase.functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'createCustomToken(uid) has failed for some reason');
       }) 
}
```

I tried using the shell method to run it locally, doing this line in command prompt: firebase functions:shell and then calling authenticationController.createCustomToken({})

which just gives me this response:
Error creating custom token:Error: Failed to determine service account. Make sure to initialize the SDK with a service account credential. Alternatively specify a service account with iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob permission. Original error: Error: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata metadata:80. Error code: ENOTFOUND

The service account seems to have the proper roles, so I don't think that's the issue.

So I was wondering if there was any way I could call me createCustomToken() function from Postman for instance, and see the response so I can test my code properly, without having an app implement the onCall method to see the results?

Or what am I missing to run this through the firebase functions:shell command?

Comment: Postman isn't going to implement the protocol that callables use on top of HTTP: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can test firebase functions on Postman using request headers as described in official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference)

First you'll have to serve your functions locally using following command at your project's root folder

```
firebase serve
```

You can also check official documentation how to serve functions locally [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator)

On running above command you'll get an http link for your function. Something like this

```
http://localhost:5000/{YOUR_FIREBASE_PROJECT_NAME}/us-central1/myFunction
```

Use that link for POST request in Postman. In the "Body" section of Postman select "Raw" then "JSON (application/json)" from dropdown and type following sample of body in the body section

```
{
    "data": {}
}
```

Adding this json object with "data" argument in the body is required as mentioned in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference#request_body). Check following screenshot for reference

[image: Screenshot displaying sample body for requesting onCall method in Postman]

Now you can send request to get response from your function. Hope it helps :)

Note: There is a mistyped "j" in the body of request in screenshot. Please ignore that.

Comment: There is no JSON(application/json) option in postman anymore. Is it equal to JSON option now?

Comment: doesnt work for me.  "message": "Bad Request",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"

Comment: @phongyewtong same for me

Comment: @phongyewtong This is working for me-- did you add the
{
    "data": {}
}
as a JSON body? I get that error when I don't pass an empty data object

Comment: i got this "The function must be called while authenticated." error

Comment: I added "content-type"="application/json" in tab "header", then it worked for me as well

Comment: be sure that you are sending a POST, not a GET

Answer (score 1):

to request a callable method with postman you should make a "POST" request with:

1. a "header" with (content-type : application/json ; charset=utf-8)
2. a "body" with a json object that has "data" key like
   {
   "data":"any data "
   }

sorce: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference